# How to center entire glossary but not column contents using leipzig package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, glossaries, multicol, leipzig

I am using the `leipzig` package for my thesis, and I would like to center the glossary horizontally on the page, but I would like for the contents of the columns to remain flushleft. I have tried variations of centering/center, tables, figures, parbox, and minipage, but to no avail. I am a beginner user of LaTeX, so the answer may be obvious. Even so, if you have any advice, I would really appreciate it.

The uncentered, normal layout:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[mcolblock,toc]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries
\setglossarystyle{inline}
\leipzigdesccapitalizetrue
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\newpage
{\Nom} {\Acc} {\Gen} {\Dat}
\end{document}
```

A failed attempt example (not sure if this is helpful for you to see):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[mcolblock,toc]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries
\setglossarystyle{inline}
\leipzigdesccapitalizetrue
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\flushleft{\printglossaries}}
\end{center}
\newpage
{\Nom} {\Acc} {\Gen} {\Dat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mcolblock` style uses a `multicol` environment to set the glossary. `multicol` by default takes the whole available horizontal space and divides it into 2 (or more) columns. Centering commands around it have no effect, since the `multicol` environment already takes the full available width and is thus already centered.

I understand that you want the columns to take only as much space as they need, and use the remaining available horizontal space to center the now-slim two-column glossary. You can do that by putting the `\printglosses` into a `minipage` environment with a fixed width that is smaller than the full available width, and center this `minipage` environment. The following example does that by putting the `minipage` macros into the `\glossarypreamble` and `\glossarypostamble` macros:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[mcolblock]{leipzig}
\usepackage{showframe}
\makeglossaries
\setglossarystyle{inline}
\leipzigdesccapitalizetrue
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}}
\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\end{minipage}\hfill}
\begin{document}
\printglosses
\newpage
{\Nom} {\Acc} {\Gen} {\Dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- I didn't use `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` because it inserts additional vertical space, but is of course also possible.
- The `showframe` package is used to display the borders of the text area on the page, to demonstrate that the glossary is actually centered.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!